# Logic separation between module content and inner backbone methods

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

Using backbone with require.js modules gives lots of freedom for functionality implementation.  Backbone structurises data a bit, but still puzzled what should i keep and where. 
For example I keep `model` fetching inside of the model as an method that I initialise from inner `initialize` and then inform (by an event `'fetched'` or `'loaded'`) dedicated view to render after successful fetch.
As well as I am leaving some wordy functionality outside of the `view` and add with the module return.

Any known practices/patterns regarding those concerns?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good topic.
I always like to keep separate responsibilities.
When i need to sync with the server, or validate some attributes, i always do that from model and listen from events on my view.

//example in coffeescript

```
//Inside the Backbone Model     
saveContent:->
    @save({},
       success:=>
            // Post Data succeeded.
            @trigger "Succeeded"
       error:=>
            // Post Data error
            @trigger "Error"
      )


 //Inside BackboneView        
 model.on("Succeeded", @renderMsgSucceeded,@)
 model.on("Error", @renderMsgError,@)
 model.saveContent()
```

I Really belive that it's **very very** important keep you data logic outside your views, Data are model's responsability, and they must know about it.

Example of bad implementation

//inside of BackboneView

```
saveContent:->
    @model.save({},
         success:=>
               @renderMsgSucceeded()                  
         error:=>
               @renderMsgError()                  
         )
```

It's clearly that you're breaking the single responsibility principle, because if someday you need to change how your model post data to server, you'll need to change you view, and it makes no sense.

I Have a blog (unfortunately in portuguese, but i'm working on a english version), there i have a post about tricks using backbone. It could be a good read.

www.rcarvalhojs.com

Comment: yeah, that is pretty much what I do, and what is prescribed by MVC approach. Though I am very surprised that so many textbooks give this way of fetching as an example....

Answer (score 1):

There are resources on the web you'd find by searching terms like "backbone patterns"; examples:

- http://ricostacruz.com/backbone-patterns/
- http://www.backbonerails.com/

The thing is, Backbone is not a framework at all, and it leaves all of the things you ask about up to the developer. The problems you cite are important, though. I've found that a good way to address them is by working through a good chunk of your project and *then* seeing what changes you'd make to better lay out your project. There is no "right" way to structure your project. Focus on producing something and then see how you can improve what you've produced with structure.

Comment: sometimes people have some approach in mind and can support why it is good or bad to do this way. i cannot say that i am that good in js project architecture, so it would be really great to look at some points. thanks anyway, dima!

Comment: seen the first link... pretty blank imho=(

Comment: @NikTerentyev I have the same problems, and my only experience has been that it varies between projects and components. You could look at how frameworks try to address this issue and take some queues for from them. I have and sometimes it's been for the better, but often pointed me down the wrong line. The other day I built a component called `App` out of a `Router` and `Views` that I took out of `routers/` and `views/`. That said, I still have all my `Model`s and `Collection`s in a module called `DataObjects`. I still have common `View`s in a `views/` folder.

Comment: But I try to focus myself, through all of this organizational stuff, to remember that organizing should be a tool to help you manage complexity and not a major source of complexity introduced into your project. I manage to overlook that all the time.

Comment: Oh, and yes, the first link is pretty blank imho too. And the second link I've seen passed around: I'm not into screencasts